# SAML 2 Signature error in ADFS 2.0

Tags: single-sign-on, wif, adfs2.0, saml-2.0, shibboleth

In our SSO scenario, we are using ADFS 2.0 as IDP and Shibboleth as SP. It is an SP-initiated sign-on. After configuring, when I try to establish communication between Shibboleth and ADFS 2.0(throw browser redirect), ADFS 2.0 is throwing the below error.

> The verification of the SAML message signature failed. 
>   Message issuer: `http://sampleserver/adfs/services/trust` 
>   Exception details: 
>   MSIS1015: Server required signed SAML AuthenticationRequest but no signature present.

Event id - 320
Related Event id - 364

```
> Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SamlProtocol.SamlProtocolSignatureVerificationException:
> MSIS1015: Server required signed SAML AuthenticationRequest but no
> signature present.    at
> Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SamlProtocol.SamlProtocolService.ValidateSignatureRequirements(SamlMessage
> samlMessage)    at
> Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SamlProtocol.SamlProtocolService.Issue(IssueRequest
> issueRequest)    at
> Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SamlProtocol.SamlProtocolService.ProcessRequest(Message
> requestMessage)
```

We haven't used any signature yet. I also have made **SignedSamlRequest** to false in ADFS properties. Signing of SAML at Shibboleth was also disabled.

I could not find any information in Microsoft site - apart from generic guide for this sort of errors.

Please advice on this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution after a lot analysis. This is a Shibboleth configuration issue. In the application defaults section, the entity ID should be unique to the application.

> ApplicationDefaults signing="false" entityID="http://URL of the protected Application "
>                           REMOTE_USER="eppn persistent-id targeted-id"

Another variation of this error happens when sigining is set to true. It will result in Signature mismatch error in ADFS.